# Suppress Python warnings in multiple threads

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-multithreading, suppress-warnings

While using `OneHotEncoder` and `GridSearchCV`, I received a series of warnings, which stated the following:

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py:182: UserWarning: Found unknown categories in columns [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] during transform. These unknown categories will be encoded as all zeros
```

I am aware that this warning is related to the `handle_unknown` parameter of `OneHotEncoder`. However, my primary concern is to suppress these warnings.

I attempted to do this by importing warnings and then using the "ignore" method, as follows:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

gs_lr = GridSearchCV(pipe, param, cv=cv, scoring='roc_auc', return_train_score=True, n_jobs=-1)
gs_lr.fit(X_trainval, y_trainval)
```

Unfortunately, this method did not work. I then discovered that it only worked if I used a single thread in `GridSearchCV`, as shown below:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

gs_lr = GridSearchCV(pipe, param, cv=cv, scoring='roc_auc', return_train_score=True, n_jobs=1)
gs_lr.fit(X_trainval, y_trainval)
```

It also worked when I manually applied `OneHotEncoder` in a single thread.

My question is, how can I suppress warnings in Python across all threads?

Answer (score 1):

according to the [warnings documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#overriding-the-default-filter) you need to set the `PYTHONWARNINGS` environment variable to reliably propagate this filter to child processes.

```py
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
os.environ["PYTHONWARNINGS"] = "ignore"
```

note that scikit-learn is using `multiprocessing` under the hood for parallelism, not `threading`, as threads already share the same filter you use in your "main thread".